# Python SFML window goes dark after a few seconds

Tags: python, sfml

So I'm learning Python and wanted to try some graphics, so I'm giving SFML a try. I wrote the following program and everything seems good, but the window goes black and white after about 6 seconds (but it keeps drawing the sprite). Am I missing something that is causing the window to go "inactive"?

```
from sfml import sf
from math import *
texture = sf.Texture.from_file('gum.png')
sprite = sf.Sprite(texture)
i = 0
w = sf.RenderWindow(sf.VideoMode(1024, 768), "Sprite Test")
w.clear()
w.active = True
while w.is_open:
    i += .1
    if i == 180:
        i = 0
    #w.clear()
    sprite.position = (cos(i) * i + 500, sin(i) * i + 350)
    w.draw(sprite)
    w.display()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to poll events. Otherwise the window won't respond to your window manager and be considered unresponsive (typically drawn in a different way, e.g. darkened or brighter).

I've never used the SFML bindings (so this might include bugs), but you'll most likely need something like this:

```
while w.is_open:
    while w.poll_event(e):
        # handle events here
    i += .1
    # Here follows your code as-is
    w.display()
```